# PHP $_SESSION variables are not persisting

Tags: php, session, http-post

I'm not quite sure why is this happening. After a bit of research and a few shots ate solving it I'm finally giving up and asking for help. My problem is that I start a session on a page (controle.php) and create an array at `$_SESSION["agenda"]`, but I only what to create it at the first time. After that I want to add elements to it with `array_push($_SESSION["agenda"], $Contato)`, where `$Contato` is an object and I create a new instance of that object for every iteration. However, the data on $_SESSION["agenda"] is not persisting, every time the code runs it creates a new array. I've tried adding session_start() to the very top of the page, checked that my browser allows sites to save cookies. As for PHP configuration I'll post a picture because I'm ignorant in this area.

Here is `phpinfo();`

[image]

controle.php code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once '../Model/Contato.php';

$op = $_GET["op"];

if (isset($op) && $op != "") {
    switch ($op) {

        case 'add':
        include '../View/novo.php';
        break;      

        case 'cad':
        if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
            $nome = $_POST["nome"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];

            $Contato = new Contato($nome, $email);

            if(!isset($_SESSION["agenda"])){
                $_SESSION["agenda"] = array();
            }
            array_push($_SESSION["agenda"], $Contato);

            include '../View/sucesso.php';
        }
        else{
            include '../View/erro.php';
        }

        unset($nome);
        unset($email);
        break;

        case 'lst':    
        include '../View/lista.php';
        break;
    }
}
else{
    include '../View/index.php';
}
?>
```

novo.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Novo Contato</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Criar novo contato</h1>
    <form action="../Controller/controle.php?op=cad" method="post">
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" required="required">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does `novo.php` also have `session_start()` at the top?

Comment: Does it need a `session_start()`? Because I'm only trying to store data in the `$_SESSION` array on controle.php.

Comment: At a first view your code seems pretty working.  Which way are you using to control the result? Is it in `lista.php`? And what do you get if you add a `print_r($_SESSION['agenda');`, say at the end of the `if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){`branch?